# wxWidgets - Switch between different view on button click

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am making a music application, I have it show like a mini-view of the app as the default view, and I want it to switch to a big view on a button click. The default/mini view has a `panel` -> `sizer` -> sub-`sizer` -> widgets. And for the big view, I have a separate `sizer` and `panel`.

The default view looks like this

[image: Mini View]

And when I press the `L` button on bottom right, I want it to switch to big view which is supposed to look like this

[image: Big View]

The top panel is empty here, I have not added widgets to it yet. I can provide additional information if required, like code snippets and all. But I want everything to be on the same `wxFrame`. I have defined all widgets in the constructor, but it overrides the previous `panel` and `sizer`. Also I want to be able to switch back and forth between the 2 layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completely replacing the frame contents like this you may find [wxSimplebook](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/classwx_simplebook.html) useful as you can then just call its `ChangeSelection()` method to switch pages. You will need to adjust the frame size, e.g. by calling `frame->SetClientSize(book->GetBestSize())`, after switching pages manually however.